# indexPath.row is not consistent

Tags: ios7, tableview, segue

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath the indexPath.row displays the right index when a cell is selected. But in the prepare for segue it always is 0 which always sends the first object into my detailView. Why is the prepareForSegue indexPath not the same as the didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.row);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetailSegue" sender:tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
}

 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailSegue"])
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSString *thisFName = [[_resultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"firstName"];
        //NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.row);
        NSString *thisLName = [[_resultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"lastName"];
        //NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",thisFName,thisLName];
        NSString *thisPhone = [[_resultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"phone"];
        //NSString *thisLName = [[_resultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"lastName"];
        NSString *thisEmail = [[_resultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"email"];

        JCDetailViewController *controller = (JCDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.firstName = thisFName;
        controller.lastName = thisLName;
        controller.phoneString = thisPhone;
        controller.emailString = thisEmail;
        NSLog(@"%@",thisFName);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the standard code produced by Apple does use the following:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

inside `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

In your method you are expecting the cell to be sender in `prepareFoeSegue:`but you send the index path of this cell

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetailSegue" sender:tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

So you should be able to use the path in your `prepareForSegue:`like

```
[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:sender];
```

Comment: Wow that was simple. That fixed it. I will accept it as an answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks again.

Comment: see my last edit, showing how you should be able to use sender as well!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. When you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` you are passing an `NSIndexPath *` for the `sender` parameter. But then in `prepareForSegue` you cast `sender` to  `UITableViewCell *`.

If you want the cell in `prepareForSegue` then pass the cell in `performSegueWithIdentifier`; otherwise, cast `sender` to `NSIndexPath *`.